# jQuery timeout plugin with iFrames

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe, frameset

I was trying to use the time out jQuery plugin below with iFrames

http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/a-new-and-improved-jquery-idle-timeout-plugin/

I am putting the main code on the page which has the framesets but the modla div can not go here. I will have to put it on one of the frames.

The problem is that it doesn't show up on timeout. I see the timer running in the header.

Any ideas? or this is something that is just not going to work with iFrames.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I resolved it by adding dialog open code in

onIdle: function(){

}